# Find column number of a specific text in vba (excel) and use its address in range function with a row that I will specify

Tags: excel, vba, range, offset

```
Sub try()
 Dim SValue As Range
   With Range("A1:Z100")

    Set SValue = .Find(What:="FF", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    If Not SValue Is Nothing Then
        Cell_Split_R = Split(SValue.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), "R")
        Cell_Split_C = Split(Cell_Split_R(1), "C")
        SRow = Cell_Split_C(0)
        SCol = Cell_Split_C(1)
        Range(SCol & "4:" & SCol & "100").Select
    End If
End With

End sub
```

'this function does not work even though the variable shows the column number when I run it.
'Any other method of getting the same result is appreciated.

I need to use this to copy columns where the headers are not always in the same position (For eg- "Receipt Number" is in A column sometimes and in R column sometimes).
I do not want to use offset with xldown as I may have blank rows in between.

Comment: `Intersect(SValue.EntireColumn, Rows("4:100")).Select`.

Comment: R1C1 returns the column as a number.  You are supplying a number not a letter to your concatenated string, so if the column you find is `D`, `4` is returned and you concatenate: `44:4100` to the Range.

Comment: @ScottCraner, This worked, really appreciate the help!

Comment: @Victor Colomb, how would I use Svalue.column in a function ?

Comment: @Arjun Khurana: Could you elaborate on your last comment?

Comment: Instead of `SRow = Cell_Split_C(0)` and `SCol = Cell_Split_C(1)`, you can use `SValue.Row` and `SValue.Column` respectivly. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.row) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.column).

Comment: @BigBen: `Rows("4:100").Columns(SValue.Column).Select` is sufficient for a contiguous range.

Comment: You're using `"A1:Z100"`, yet `Rows("4:100")`. Could you share in which row(s) you are planning to search for the title (header)? Are you looking for a function that would return the column number of the found title (header): `Dim sCol As Long: sCol = GetCol(Rows(3), "FF"): Rows("4:100").Columns(sCol).Select`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 the headers are present on The first row and the data I need to copy lie between rows 4 and 100 below that header.PS, thanks for helping me get a way to use it in a function!

Comment: @Victor Colomb, thank you for that, I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

### Get Column Number vs Find First Match

- In your case, the first solution is just fine.

**Get Column Number**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectUsingColumnNumber()

    Const hRow As Long = 1
    Const sCols As String = "A:Z"
    Const sRows As String = "4:100"
    
    Const Title As String = "FF"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim sCol As Long: sCol = GetColumnNumber(ws.Columns(sCols), Title, hRow)
    If sCol = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The title '" & Title & "' was not found in row '" _
            & hRow & "'.", vbCritical, "Select Column Range"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ws.Rows("4:100").Columns(sCol).Select
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a row ('RowNumber') of a range ('rg'), returns
'               the worksheet column number of the first cell
'               whose value is equal to a string ('Title'). Case-insensitive.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetColumnNumber( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    ByVal Title As String, _
    Optional ByVal RowNumber As Long = 1) _
As Long
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If RowNumber < 1 Then Exit Function
    If RowNumber > rg.Rows.Count Then Exit Function
    Dim fCell As Range
    With rg.Rows(RowNumber)
        Set fCell = .Find(Title, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    End With
    If fCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    GetColumnNumber = fCell.Column
End Function
```

**To Utilize the Matching Cell Reference**

```
Sub SelectUsingCell()

    Const hRow As Long = 1
    Const sCols As String = "A:Z"
    Const sRows As String = "4:100"
    
    Const Title As String = "FF"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim fCell As Range
    Set fCell = RefFirstMatchInRow(ws.Columns(sCols), Title, hRow)
    If fCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The title '" & Title & "' was not found in row '" _
            & hRow & "'.", vbCritical, "Select Column Range"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ws.Rows("4:100").Columns(fCell.Column).Select

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a row ('RowNumber') of a range ('rg'), creates
'               a reference to the first cell whose value is equal
'               to a string ('Title'). Case-insensitive.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefFirstMatchInRow( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    ByVal Title As String, _
    Optional ByVal RowNumber As Long = 1) _
As Range
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If RowNumber < 1 Then Exit Function
    If RowNumber > rg.Rows.Count Then Exit Function
    With rg.Rows(RowNumber)
        Set RefFirstMatchInRow _
            = .Find(Title, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    End With
End Function
```